# How to I create an expiration date in my django model?

Tags: django, django-models

How would I create an expiration date option for new posts that would only show when they are unexpired?

Answer (score 4):

In your model you need something like this:

```
expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then in your views you could access the database like this:

```
def UnexpiredPosts(request):
    unexpired_posts = YourPostModelName.objects.filter(expiration_date__gt = datetime.now())

    return render(request, "path_to_template", {'Posts': unexpired_posts})
```

The template:

```
<ul>
{% for i in Posts %}
<li>{{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```