# How to implement a user access based on licenses using custom permissions and APIView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-permissions

I have the following models.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()

class User(AbstractUser):
    pen_name = models.Charfield()
```

I want to restrict a user to create a specific number of posts (let's say 10) and no more than that. Also, I want the permission to expire by a certain date.

These models are representative, my original models have many more fields and need many more permissions. But for all of those, I basically need to restrict the count and expiry date. I want to have a licensing functionality by using the permissions. So a user may purchase a license to make 'n' posts in a year.

How do I achieve this, for APIViews and permission_classes in DRF?

Comment: Why are you not using [DRF Permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu In DRF permissions how can I store an expiry date for each user and the allowed post count for each user. As that may be different for each user. That is why I wanted to use Django permissions

Comment: Store the *post owner* and *post created time* in `Post` model. You can query those values to check the conditions

Comment: The expiration duration also may not be same for all the users. As I want the permissions to behave more like a license. As a user may purchase a license to make 'n' posts in a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For licenses, you can create a License model

```
class License(models.Model):
    code = models.Charfield()
    count = models.Integerfield()
    #other fields for license information
```

and then you can have the licenses in a ManyToManyField to the User model

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    licenses = models.ManyToManyField(License)
    ...
```

You can also add a through model for the M2M relationship to store other details like the date purchase of the license, expiry date, record of transaction etc.

And then in the APIViews you can use DRF's custom permission class

```
class MyPermissionClass(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        #process user's licenses to check permissions
```

```
class MyView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [MyPermissionClass,]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a field(`post_number`) for your custom `User` and this field can be `IntegerField` or `PositiveIntegerField` and you can make it [limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849142/how-to-limit-the-maximum-value-of-a-numeric-field-in-a-django-model).

[How to  create an expiration date in my django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338357/how-to-i-create-an-expiration-date-in-my-django-model/19338464)

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    post_number = models.IntegerField()
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()

    more_restrictions = models.ManyToManyField(MyRestrictionModel)

    # rest of your code...
```

For more restrictions you can make a relationship with `MyRestrictionModel` and whenever you add a field to `MyRestrictionModel` your `User` will be restricted.

Comment: So the post number is only one of the restrictions. I have more complex models that this and I may need to add some permissions dynamically. So I need a way of storing the count and expiry date for a permission. I'll update my question to mention this.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this can be useful. @Vikramark